# Why isn't std::set (or std::map) using the three-way comparator efficiently?

Tags: c++, stl, set, comparator

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct foo {
    foo (int i) : i {i} {}
    auto operator<=> (const foo& other) const {
      std::cout << "Call (" << i << "," << other.i << ")" << std::endl;
      return i <=> other.i;
    }
    int i = 0;
};

int main () {
  auto m = std::set <foo> ();

  m.insert (3);
  std::cout << "Inserting 8" << std::endl;
  m.insert (8);
  std::cout << "Checking 3" << std::endl;
  m.contains (3);
  std::cout << "Checking 8" << std::endl;
  m.contains (8);
  std::cout << "Checking 5" << std::endl;
  m.contains (5);
}
```

This outputs:

```
Inserting 8
Call (8,3)
Call (3,8)
Call (8,3)
Checking 3
Call (3,3)
Call (3,3)
Checking 8
Call (3,8)
Call (8,8)
Call (8,8)
Checking 5
Call (3,5)
Call (8,5)
Call (5,8)
```

I would have expected that `operator<=>` would be called once for the first insertion, maybe twice, but three times seems very much wasteful.  Similarly, all the comparisons to search for elements check for both `(x, y)` and `(y, x)`, not leveraging `operator<=>`.

**Question:** Why isn't `std::set` using the full power of `operator<=>` ?

Comment: std::set only uses its template parameter (std::less by default) for comparisons. Changing this behavior now would be complicated...

Comment: it needs at least 2 to know if the two values are equivalent, because it uses only `<` not `==`. The third call is strange

Comment: What happens if you add in an `operator==`?  That may eliminate 2 of the calls.  (Just as speculation, I don't know.)  Was this compiled with `-O3`?

Comment: Just step into it in a debugger. Pretty much all compilers these days ship with the source for the standard library.

Comment: @MarcGlisse well, it could check `std::three_way_comparable` @463035818_is_not_a_number Two calls are from `std::_Rb_tree::_M_get_insert_unique_pos`, one from `std::_Rb_tree::::_M_insert_`, all called from `std::_Rb_tree::_M_insert_unique`.

Comment: @Eljay Adding `operator==` or `-O3` doesn't change anything, sadly…

Comment: @Michaël `set` and `map` dont check for equality (`==`), but equivalence (via `<`). See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). `a` and `b` are equivalent when `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`. Thats the minimum 2 calls. Not sure if `insert` could do withotu the 3rd

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks! I do understand this.  What I'm suggesting is that set or map would call the `operator<=>` _once_ and deduce whatever it needs from this.  I'm surprised that `operator<=>` made it into the language without this natural variant of `set` and `map` being implemented, and wondering if there's a reason I'm not seeing.